# Can you override a Publicnoncreatable program to apply its TLB?

Tags: vb.net, ocx, sketchup, tlb

I have referenced the SketchUp.exe into a project or at times an extracted TLB from the SketchUp.exe and can see the object model but cannot create an instance of any object in it.

I found out it may be a non-shared object or set to PublicNoncreatable and thus unlike AutoCAD or Excel I cannot create object instances.

When working with Adobe Acrobat I found it had the same problem but had a non-viewable object name which allowed instancing its objects.

Maybe SketchUp also has a completely hidden object or method that allows this. In the mean time is there a way to apply and instance of the object by overriding its non-share status as shared?

Answer (score 0):

SketchUp's COM API is no longer supported. You may want to take a look at the new [C API](https://extensions.sketchup.com/en/developer_center/sketchup_sdk).